# Fixed and Free Shipping Methods

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, free-shipping

Hopefully someone can help me with my shipping methods.

Current set up has:

1. Table Rates Price vs Destination - $0-$100 free, > $100 $7.50 Shipping.
2. Fixed Rate = $0 for Pick up from store option.

This works fine but we have added gift card products which can cost less than $100 but shouldn't cost to ship. So I have set up a shopping cart rule that gives 'free shipping' on Gift Card Products. This seems to work in cost calculations but in the checkout there is no selection for shipping it automatically selects "Pick up from store $0" option not 'Free Shipping'

What should happen is that if there is a gift card product in the cart the options should be '**Free shipping**' and '**Pick up**'

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This extension will definitely help you

[Flat rate per product extention](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html)

This extension is to set a custom flat rate for each product.

Also you can set your own custom rules in their Model file.

Install it and let me know.